# Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Compile Question

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers, and i am using the gcc to compile at the moment. How can i change it to compile with a Green Hills compiler? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not specifically familiar with the Green Hills compilers, however what you need is to switch to a different tool chain. This can be done in the project properties, under `C/C++ build >> Tool Chain Editor`.

Check out your package for some sort of Green Hills tool-chain for eclipse CDT. If you find one, check out their documentation and/or CDT's for more help (sorry I can't help you here).

Also, you can create a 'makefile' project, which allows you full control over every aspect of your project build (including the compiler selection). It might be possible to convert an existing CDT project to a custom makefile project, but I wouldn't count on it.
You can check out the makefiles that were generated by CDT for your current project, and modify them to use a different compilation command manually.

Hope this points you in the right direction...